# Is there any wrong? i want to compare many word in a variable from user input in linux

Tags: linux, unix

echo "RTE"
echo "GTA"
echo "PTC"
echo "DDC"
                                                                                                                                      echo -e "Enter the code:\c"
read code

name=[[ 'RTE' || 'GTA' || 'PTC' || 'DDC' ]]

if [ $code == $name ]
then
echo "You choose $code"
else
echo "Try again.. NO option."
fi

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Can you please edit code and remove extra blanks

Comment: Use a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps something like:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

code=$1
case $code in
(RTE|GTA|PTC|DDC) echo "You choose $code";;
(*) echo "Try again. NO option.";;
esac
$ ./a.sh PTC
You choose PTC
$ ./a.sh foo
Try again. NO option.
```